# How to match the case and apply templates

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML line of code.

```
<title><page>651</page>CHAPTER 13 This is <content-style font-style="italic">This goes in content-style</content-style> The title</title>
```

Here i'm trying to do the below.

Get the number after `CHAPTER` and concat it with `Chapter`, i'm able to do it with the below code.

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('Chapter ', substring-before(substring-after(child::title,' '),' ')"/>
```

ignore the `page` in the `title`, and i use the below template match and able to do it.

```
<xsl:template match="title/page"/>
```

If there is just plain data, i'm using the below to get it.

```
<xsl:value of select ="substring-after(substring-after(./title,' '),' ')">
```

But the problem came in the above type, here i need to apply templates on `substring-after(substring-after(.,' '),' ')` and unfortunately this is not working.

I have the below XSLT

```
<xsl:template match ="title">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="content-style">
        <xsl:variable name="fontStyle">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('font-style-',@font-style)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <span class="{$fontStyle}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="para"/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
```

**expected O/P**

```
<div class="chapter-title">
                    <span class="chapter-num">Chapter 13</span><br /><br /> This is <span class="font-style-italic">This goes in content-style</span> the title</span></div>
```

Can you please let me know how can i do this.

Thanks

Comment: The result of substring-after() is a string, not a node, and you can't (until XSLT 3.0) apply templates to strings. Rather that telling us what you are doing that fails, try telling us what problem you are trying to solve: what are the inputs and outputs of your transformation? Without that information, all we can tell you is that whatever you are trying to do, you are going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output has an unmatched span end tag.

Ignoring that, I would do something like:

```
<xsl:template match ="title">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content-style">
        <span class="font-style-{@font-style}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title/text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="Chapter [0-9]+">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <span class="chapter-num">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </span><br/>>br/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:-nonmatching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Michael Kay, sorry for the delayed response, this is not working as expected. Here the working demo http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBte, can you please have a look into it. Thanks